# GridView Header and Footer with header filled the screen width

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, android-gridview

Hi I am working on GridView which has header and footer.

In my case, the header's width should fill the screen width like below

[image: Image- header filled the screen width]

But I am getting the header filled the grid items' width.

I have used the [library](https://github.com/liaohuqiu/android-GridViewWithHeaderAndFooter).

What should I have to do to make the header's width match with screen width.

Note : The header only should filled the screen width not the grid items. And the grid items should have right and left margins.

Comment: Without even using any library... Couldn't you simply add the header **outside** the GridView (any View could do the trick)?

Comment: @Der Golem The header should scroll with the gridview. Is any other possible way ?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Except `faking a GridView` by using a ListView.

Answer (score 0):

Use the HFGridview 
`https://github.com/SergeyBurish/HFGridView/tree/master/HFGridView

By this you will acheve waht you want with little bit customisation. I already implemented that. If you face any problem let me know I will share code with you.